# How do I preserve leading and trailing zeros in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to read a number from a database and write it to an excel file, but I am having trouble keeping leading and trailing zeros. When I checked it, I was able to see that while reading the data, PHP is treating it as a number instead of a string. I have tried type casting and concatenation of the value with an empty string. However, the following code

```
<?php
    $a = (string) 180961.65000;
    echo $a;
?>
```

gets the below output

> 180961.65

How would I preserve the zeroes?

Comment: You might want to give [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) a go.

Comment: @user2484796 Was going to give editing your post a shot, but just wanted to check one thing before I do: Are you *writing out* data to an excel file, or are you actually *reading from* an excel file (and narrowed down the problem to the given snippet)

Comment: The number _format() wont be executed as it will append commas and the number of decimal points differs in each of the records. The value is read from the database and written to the excel file.

Comment: Is this a real Excel file (BIFF format) or a CSV or HTML file that you're writing? If the former, then setting a format mask for the cell should be available to your code, depending on what library you're using to write it

Answer (score 2):

you can try this.

```
$number = 180961.65000;
$string = sprintf("%f",$number);
echo $string;
//result:180961.650000
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use quotes to identify $a as string (also use quotes with echo if possible):

```
$a = "180961.65000";
echo "$a";
```

Comment: But the issue is that the value is retrieved from the database and not a direct assignment

Comment: Try the one by @AllenLu

Answer (score 0):

You need **number_format** for this

> Reference -  http://php.net/number_format

```
 $a =  "180961.650000000";
 $total_len =  strlen($a);
 $dec_pos =  strpos($a, ".");
 $diff = $total_len - ($dec_pos +1);
 $a = number_format($a,$diff);
 $a = str_replace(",", "", $a);
  echo $a;
```

Comment: The problem is "php misses leading or landing zeros". Your answer doesn't work if his/her number has i.e. 8 decimals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
The value needs to match the database records and the existence of comma will make the process to fail

Comment: Making changes to my post please see the updates.. I have remove the comma. you will get the no as you want. no compromise in that

Comment: That's a good one. If the `,` is a problem change the line `$a = number_format($a,$diff);` to `$a = number_format($a,$diff,".","");`. That should set the thousands_sep to nothing.

Comment: And then remove the `$a = str_replace(",", "", $a);`

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work if you remove the quotes from the first line :(

Comment: And as it's not a direct assignment, but from DB, there'll be no quotes. The code above (without quotes): [link](https://www.airpett.com/test.php)

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
<?php
    $a = (string) "180961.65000";
    echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: HI 
The double quotes can not be added here since the assignment is not a direct assignment. The value is retrieved from the database and assigned to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

The data type is changing automatically in an unclear way somewhere, while working with the variable.

Therefore I suggest to preserve the leading and trailing digits explicitly while the variable is still a string. Then add them later when the variable has become a number. It might look ugly, but it is flexible for any number of zeroes.

Like this:

```
// Example number, assume it was received by database
$input = "00018096.16500000";

// Get the leading and trailing zeros as string. 
preg_match("/^0+/", $input, $leading);
preg_match("/0+$/", $input, $trailing);
// Mark if there is a decimal point.
$hasDigit = strpos($input, ".") !== false;  


// Only for here: force the input to become a number, thus removing all trailing and leading zeros.
$input = 1 * $input;


// Now add the leading and trailing zeroes again and turn the variable back to a string. 
$saveOutput = $input . "";
if (count($leading) > 0) {
    $saveOutput = $leading[0] . $saveOutput;    
}

// If the number is not a float with decimal point, don't add the trailing zeros as they are still there in the integer number. 
if (count($trailing) > 0 && $hasDigit) {
    $saveOutput = $saveOutput . $trailing[0];
}

// Show result
echo $saveOutput;

// --> Result:
// 00018096.16500000
```

N.B., I call the variable `saveOutput` because you are sure it is a string and it won't change, like the `input`.